# Having difficult to generate a directed graph with igraph and networkd3

Tags: r, igraph, networkd3

I have a xlsx contains about 2000+ nodes and 9000 edges. And I want to generate a explicit directed graph. I tried igraph package in R to generate the directed graph I want but (1) it is too many nodes and edges to print clearly.I refer some documents that using networkd3 to convert igraph to networkd3 and plot,but(2) the direction(arrows) lost.
Would you please help me out these sitution? Either (1) or (2).My codes belows,and my data format like 
edges1.xlsx
source  target attr
s1      s2     a
s2      s7     b
s2      s3     c

nodes1.xlsx
id  attr
s1  a
s2  c
s3  d
s4  c

```
library(readxl)
library(igraph)
links <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\file\\Desktop\\1W\\edges1.xlsx",sheet=1,col_names = TRUE)
nodes <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\file\\Desktop\\1W\\nodes1.xlsx",sheet=1,col_names = TRUE)
net   <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links,vertices=unique(nodes$JYZH),directed = T)
plot(net, vertex.color="orange",vertex.size=.1,vertex.label=NA,vertex.label.color="black",vertex.label.dist=0,edge.arrow.size=.01)
#above work well with my data format but because it is too many nodes(2000+) and edges(9000+) to print clearly
library(networkD3)

#Use igraph to make the graph and find membership
wc <- cluster_walktrap(net)
members <- membership(wc)

#Convert to object suitable for networkD3
net_d3  <- igraph_to_networkD3(net,group = members)
forceNetwork(Links = net_d3$links, Nodes = net_d3$nodes,
         Source = 'source', Target = 'target', NodeID = 'name',Group = 'group', zoom = TRUE)
#using above code of networkd3,the direction lost.....
```

Is there any solutions to solve these problems?

Answer (score 2):

1. A network graph with 2000+ nodes and 9000 edges is going to be messy no matter which software you use to generate it. What do you hope will be different if you plot it with networkD3?
2. **UPDATE (2017.03.24)**: This feature (using arrowheads to show the direction of edges/links) is in the most recent released version (0.4) of networkD3 with the `arrows = TRUE` argument to `forceNetwork()`.

Comment: Also, just so you know, using `networkD3` to plot a network graph with 2000+ nodes and 9000 links will be very slow, and (probably) practically unusable. You should definitely open it in a browser window (as opposed to viewing it in RStudio's 'Viewer' tab) to have *any* chance of being able to interact with it.

Comment: I'm loving `networkD3`. Thanks to you and others for it!

Comment: Thank you Yetman.You save me.For problem 1,yes I want to use networkd3 to present a clear network.Of course, like you mentioned, I failed.The graph generated by networkd3 is slowly.Actually, I have 1 million+ nodes to present. What kind of compute power can deal with this?IBM mainframe or cloud? 2.I will try to update the devleop version to add on arrows.Thank you so much for you effort on improve the package.I love it.Plus, Is there really no way to present so much nodes clearly?

Comment: @c-han the large amount of processing power that's being used with networkD3 is due to re-calculating the node and link positions and redrawing or positioning the elements many times per second so that it looks like a smooth animation. I suspect that some software could calculate the positions of 1m+ nodes and only plot them once after the positions had been calculated, thereby saving on a lot of processing power. In fact, another feature of networkD3 that is potentially on the horizon is to generate a 'static' plot, which would do exactly that.

Comment: So, I bet you could find some software to plot 1m+ nodes, but the more important question is... what would that look like? Can you imagine any plausible arrangement of 1m+ plus nodes that would be a viable, visual representation? Think about it.... if you had a 1000x1000 pixel image, every single pixel in the image would be needed to represent each node at a unique 1x1 pixel position. I think maybe you need to rethink what you're trying to achieve... maybe work with subsets of your data?

Comment: Thank you for your information.Perhaps I need to analysis the subsets of data and present a clear picture.Thank you for your help.